# Connect angular with mongo db

Tags: angular, spring, mongodb

I'm building a table gui with angular. For that i needed to retrieve data from mongo db. So i wants to know how to connect both of them inorder display data in mongo db on angular gui table.I did this by mongo db community server not by atlas. Is there any way to connect both angular and mongo db using spring.

Comment: You can not direct connect database with your front end because it is vulnerable and your database credentials are open. that's why you need the backend to connect with database. Hope this helps! Please check https://medium.com/@BaaniLeen/connecting-angular-5-app-to-mongodb-database-mean-stack-9b4b4232e219

Comment: In this link there it is unable to complete the step 2 it made an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a back-end, MongoDB is a database, you should not make database operations with the front-end, that's really unsafe. Create an easy app with NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. Then you'll be able to do that.

NodeJS App is the bridge between your DB and your front-end.

**EDITED**

Here is a tutorial of how to do it using **MEAN** (MongoDB, ExpressJS, Angular and NodeJs), It's kinda long, but it's truly complete.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0iGvadr_Cc&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 0):

You should not be directly communicating from angular application to mongodb, you should introduce a server (like node.js) to communicate with mongodb and expose the APIs which your angular application(client) will consume.

Angular -> Node.js -> MongoDB

Comment: Can you send me an appropriate link for that.

Comment: @BawanthaWickramarachchi this looks pretty relevant
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-5-crud-opration-using-nodeexpressmongo/